# Access lastMeasurement in HTML widget

Tags: cumulocity

I want to reference the last measurment of a device in a HTML widget.
The page https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/cockpit/ give samples to access these.

My attempt to show the TemperatureMeasurement doesn't return a result:

```
{{devices[391].lastMeasurement.c8y_TemperatureMeasurement.T}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible from the HTML widget. You can only access the data inside the managedObject from there.

Maybe try using the SCADA widget for that and create your custom content as SVG instead of HTML.